# please see "greatest hits"

Tags: discussion

[How can we utilize the "Greatest hits" list for our sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103650/how-can-we-utilize-the-greatest-hits-list-for-our-sites/104920#104920)

> In particular, look for questions that got a large number of anonymous feedback in relation to the total number of views. These posts are ideal candidates for aggressive maintenance.

Here's a clicky link for parenting greatest hits:
https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits

It's an interesting list.